# Channel creation failed

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am a complete newbie on Hyperledger Fabric and as described in the docs I installed all the prerequisites and set up the Network Artifacts. But after i want to bring Up the Network. I get this error and i don't know what to do:

```
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orde
rer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: x509: certificate signed
by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" whi
le trying to verify candidate authority certificate "tlsca.example.com")
Usage:
  peer channel create [flags]

Flags:
  -c, --channelID string   In case of a newChain command, the channel ID to crea
te.
  -f, --file string        Configuration transaction file generated by a tool su
ch as configtxgen for submitting to orderer
  -t, --timeout int        Channel creation timeout (default 5)

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded
trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded
X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating wi
th the orderer endpoint
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded
private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides,
 see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when va
lidating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the
orderer endpoint
  -v, --version                             Display current version of fabric pe
er server

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

OS: Windows 7
Hyperledger Fabric: 1.1
Latest Docker installation

Comment: This is running the first-network tutorial? This can happen if there is an orderer running from a previous sample/tutorial. Be sure that there are no docker containers running before you start the tutorial.

Comment: what command do i have to run in the docker terminal to kill all docker containers?

Comment: i ran the command `docker ps -aq` and i still get this error: `Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of
 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts to get the network running i created containers which i had to delete with the command `docker ps -aq`. Also i had to get the network down before that with the command `./byfn.sh -m down`. Then i restarted everything by using `byfn.sh -m generate -c mychannel` and `byfn.sh -m up -c mychannel -s couchdb` Then everything worked as in the docs described.